# JS return multiple promises in one function

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I have the following JS function:

```
function function1() {
    return Promise.all([promise1(),promise2()]);
}
```

I am calling this function with other promises asynchronously using:

```
(async function() {
    await function1();
    await promise3();
}())
```

But with `Promise.all`, it runs the promises synchronously. I am wondering how do I define `function1` such that:

1. The promises run asynchronously
2. It returns values resolved by both promises so that I would be able to use `async` `await` on `function1`

I tried:

```
async function function1() {
    await promise1();
    return promise2();
}
```

But it only returns the resolved value of `promise2` and not `pomise1.`

Comment: `"But with Promise.all, it runs the promises synchronously"`??? That's not true. `Promise.all` just waits for all of the Promises to be resolved, before firing the function passed to it's `.then` method.

Comment: `promise1` and `promise2` will run at the same time and when they are done, `promise3` will start. Here is an example https://jsbin.com/tebubeducu/edit?js,console

Comment: Your terminology is making it really hard to understand your question.  Promises don't "run" anything.  You call a function and it returns a promise.  A promise is an object that provides a notification mechanism.  You don't "run" a promise.  You run a function.  You use a returned promise to know when some asynchronous operation is done and what it's resolved value or rejected error is.  Pseudo-code like `promise1()` really confuses things.  It should be `func1()` where func1 returns a promise.

Comment: And, your statement that "promises run synchronously" doesn't make any sense.  Promises don't "run" in the first place and secondly, promises are usually used and returned by asynchronous operations that don't run synchronously either.

Comment: Of course `return promise2();` returns the promise that `promise2()` returned so the resolved value will be the resolved value of THAT promise.  How could you expect anything different?  That's what you're returning.  You are completely ignoring the resolved values from `promise1()`.  You wait for them, but then drop their resolved values on the floor, not assigning them to anything or returning them.  If you want to return an array of resolved values that include the ones returned from `promise1()`, then put all three values in an array  and return that array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return multiple variables from a function by returning them as an array, like so:

```js
return [thing1, thing2]
```

[`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) actually creates all of the Promises at the same time, so they are not happening sequentially; however, if you `await` or `.then()` the result of `Promise.all()`, then it will wait for *all* of those Promises to finish before continuing execution.

`function1()` is actually working as you are wanting it to. It should be returning an array with the results of `promise1()` and `promise2()`. Then in your other function, you are waiting for those Promises to finish, but doing nothing with the results. If you want to do something with the result, save that to a variable, like this:

```js
(async function() {
    const [promise1Results, promise2Results] = await function1();
    await promise3();
}())
```

I've written a small code snippet to show how it could work, although I'm not quite positive of your end goal.

```js
function promise1() {
  return Promise.resolve(1)
}

function promise2() {
  return Promise.resolve(2)
}

function promise3() {
  return Promise.resolve(3)
}

function function1() {
  return Promise.all([promise1(), promise2()])
}

async function main() {
  const [promise1Result, promise2Result] = await function1()
  const promise3Result = await promise3()
  
  console.log(promise1Result)
  console.log(promise2Result)
  console.log(promise3Result)
}

main()
```

***UPDATE***

To run `promise1` and `promise2` sequentially and return both results, do not call them in `Promise.all()`. Instead, await them both and save their results to variables, and return both in an array.

```js
function promise1() {
  return Promise.resolve(1)
}

function promise2() {
  return Promise.resolve(2)
}

async function function1() {
  const promise1Result = await promise1()
  const promise2Result = await promise2()
  return [promise1Result, promise2Result]
}

async function main() {
  const bothResults = await function1()
  console.log(bothResults)

  const [promise1Result, promise2Result] = bothResults
  console.log(promise1Result)
  console.log(promise2Result)
}

main()
```

Comment: Hi Kevin, thanks for the reply. In that case Promise1 and Promise2 will execute at the same time. I would like to have Promise1 execute before Promise2. Thanks

Comment: That means you want `promise1` and `promise2` to happen synchronously, which you can achieve by awaiting both of them in `function1`, saving their output to variables, and returning them in an array. Will update my solution to show what I mean.

Comment: "*`Promise.all()` actually does kick off all of the Promises at the same time*" - no! `Promise.all` doesn't kick off anything, it just creates a promise that waits for the inputs. One does kick off an asynchronous tasks when *creating* the promise.

Comment: Btw, please don't use the term "*synchronously*" when you mean "sequentially". The execution is still asynchronous.

Comment: @Bergi Yep, good points, bad wording on my part. Editing to fix now.

Comment: Hi the updated answer really helps. Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can just return an array of promises like `return [promise1(), promise2()]` and then handle them in another method